# MySQL 5.5 installation error: this installation package could not be opened

Tags: windows, installation, mysql

I downloaded mysql-5.5.13-win32.msi from SQL server site. When I try to execute that file, it gives an error saying, "this installation package could not be opened. contact the application vendor to verify this is a valid windows installer package."

I have read couple of posts talking about corrupted package and Windows Installer might not be installed properly. Should I download again from zip file or so? Or should I try to download the MSI file itself one more time?
Is there any other work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you are using a 32-bit OS, and if so, download it again. It sounds like it may be corrupt or the wrong version.

Lastly, it could be a corrupt file in this directory: Windows\Installer folder. Delete any files with an .msi extension (You may need to enable viewing the extensions).

Comment: how to check whether it is 32 bit or not? windows xp with SP2.

Comment: @vani Do Start>Run and type in winver and hit enter. If it is 64-bit, it will say x64 clearly, but if it is 32-bit, it will say nothing. Here is what the 64-bit looks like: http://www.spywaredrguide.com/VirtualDr/images/xppro64bit_winver_01.gif

Comment: thank you Kcorreau, Should i delete windows installer and then install again from microsoft site?

Comment: Yes, I would delete the download, and re-download it. It may be something else, but it could simply be corrupt, so rule out the easy thing first.

Comment: it is 32 bit, i think there is some problem in file download, size is nto the same as mentioned in my SQL website. downloading again.